# Upvote icon appears enabled when upvoting is impossible

Tags: bug, closed-questions, comments, meta

I tried to upvote a comment just now and got a message saying that the comment couldn't be upvoted.

[image: A pointing-hand cursor hovering over the upvote button. The tooltip is "this comment adds something useful to the post" but a red popout says "This comment is not eligible for voting and flagging."]

As far as I can tell, this issue occurs on all on-hold questions in Meta.

(I'm not sure of the best resolution to this bug, so I've put multiple answers below.  Upvote the one that seems best and/or downvote the others.)

Comment: Because the issue only affects meta, this post belongs on a meta-meta site. ;p

Comment: FWIW, this happens on all sites for deleted and locked posts. What's special on meta is that closed / on-hold posts are treated as if they were locked.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern on the site seems to be:

1. to disable features you don't have permissions for and give a message explaining why (for example the Review queues)
2. to hide features that are not relevant to the current context (for example, the answer box on closed questions)

Because the button is not applicable to the current context (but may be applicable on the main UX.SE), it should be **hidden only on Meta** (where it is disabled).

Comment: Tangentially, there are many exceptions to part #1: off the top of my head, the close / delete links for posts are only shown if you have the necessary privileges for those actions (and the post is eligible for them). The "rule of thumb" seems to be that actions which new users might reasonably expect to be able to do, or whose existence SE wants to advertise to new users even if they can't use them yet, are shown but disabled, whereas features that are deemed potentially confusing to new users are hidden. Still, I do feel this would be the right choice here: +1.

Answer (score 0):

Because this issue only applies to meta but not the main site, a standard should be adopted for the two sites.  The upvote button for comments should be **hidden on both Meta and the main site.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this proposal correctly. Why should we hide the button on the main site, if it works there?

Comment: @Ilmari, its possible that the real issue is an inconsistency between meta and the main site.  In that case, either both should have comment functionality enabled or both should have it disabled (and hidden).  (There may be some reason to enable comments on only the main site, but if there is, I don't know what it is.)  I also posted a third answer option of **enabling** on both Meta and the main site but that option has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Because this issue only applies to meta but not the main site, a standard should be adopted for the two sites.  The upvote button for comments should be **enabled on both Meta and the main site.**